Table page overflow with images
I am creating a table of images for a report using the tabular environment. Unfortunately, the table keeps going over the page boundary and into the "void", and I can't seem to break the table and continue it on the next page. I have so far tried using Longtable and ltablex but it keeps moving over the page boundaries.
Here is a shortened version of my syntax for reference:
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Cool title\label{tab: cool label}}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
Image plane & Fourier plane.\footnote{The size of the images has been modified so you can see the Fourier plane. Care was taken to ensure no data was lost}\\
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}\centering\includegraphics[width=0.95\columnwidth]{Data/EX4IB.png}\caption{\label{fig:EX4IB}}\end{subfigure}&
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}\centering\includegraphics[width=0.95\columnwidth]{Data/EX4FB.png}\caption{\label{fig:EX4FB}}\end{subfigure}\\
\newline
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}\centering\includegraphics[width=0.95\columnwidth]{Data/EX4IS.png}\caption{\label{fig:EX4IS}}\end{subfigure}&
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}\centering\includegraphics[width=0.95\columnwidth]{Data/EX4FS.png}\caption{\label{fig:EX4FS}}\end{subfigure}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Thanks in advance

Have a look at the longtable package or use longtblr from the tabularray package to allow page breaks.
